# Select distinct rows with same value in another column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table like this:

```
+--------+----------+
|PersonID|IsDomestic|
+--------+----------+
|1       |1         |
+--------+----------+
|1       |0         |
+--------+----------+
|2       |1         |
+--------+----------+
|2       |1         |
+--------+----------+
|2       |1         |
+--------+----------+
|1       |1         |
+--------+----------+
|3       |0         |
+--------+----------+
|4       |1         |
+--------+----------+
```

If the same PersonId have at least one 0 value in IsDomestic column then shouldn't return this PersonId but if PersonId have only 1 values then should return this PersonId but only once. This is result from the table:

```
+--------+
|PersonID|
+--------+
|2       |
+--------+
|4       |
+--------+
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you need is a `HAVING` with a conditional aggregate:

```sql
SELECT PersonID
FROM dbo.YourTable
GROUP BY PersonID
HAVING COUNT(CASE IsDomestic WHEN 0 THEN 1 END) = 0;
```